# Need guidance with html form file upload using Dotster

Tags: php, html

First off, I have no experience with PHP. I'm setting up a form on a site that is hosted on Dotster using their  link. This works to send an email with all of the info, but the file that is selected for upload disappears. Does not end up on the server, does not attach to the email. Are there any ways to determine or control where the file goes using their script?

```
<form method="post" action="https://www1.dotster.com/scripts/formemail.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="my_email" value="flyboyjr@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Nomination Form">
        <h1>Nominee Information</h1>
<label for="photo">Please upload a photo of the nominee in uniform or sports attire appropriate with
                their
                nomination. Please make sure it includes a clear view of their face.</label><br><br>
            <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" required>
```

Comment: No, we can not tell you what a script that we have no access to does exactly. Where did you get this script from? Where there no instructions / documentation on how to use it?

Comment: Here's the instructions from Dotster relating to the script. Everything else covered was about the html to build a basic form

Getting started
Create an HTML form with the following tags:
A standard <form> tag that contains the path to the Form->Email processing script

<form method= "post" action="https://www1.dotster.com/scripts/formemail.html">
A hidden tag. This tag means it cannot be seen by your customers and tells the form where to e-mail the contents of the form.

<input type="hidden" name="my_email" value="youremail">

Comment: You are probably referring to https://www.dotster.com/help/article/form-email, I assume. I don't see it mention _anything_ about adding file uploads to the email. You will probably have to ask them if that feature even exists.

Comment: I asked them, they said it could be done with the right code on my end. That's about all they could tell me. Thank you for your help, I'm going to have to do something else entirely

Comment: As for uploading a file with an HTML form, there is nothing more you could do here on your end - everything needed for that (method=POST, the proper enctype, and a file input field), is already given in your form. If anything else besides that is needed, their documentation or their support would have to tell you what that is, can't be guessed from the outside.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I appreciate you commenting on something like this even though it probably seemed like a waste of time